# MapStateToPros returning undefined in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux

My `mapStateToProps` is giving me undefined and I have no idea why.
Could you please explain to me and tell me how to fix it?

```
      const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            currencieList : state.currencieList
        };
    };
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            actions: bindActionCreators(
                {
                    getCurrencies,
                },
                dispatch
            ),
        };
    };
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage);
```

Here is my store :

```
 const initialState = {
    currencieList : []
}
```

The error which is popping up is saying this :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'currencieList' of undefined
```

Comment: Are you using redux connect, if so add the code for it

Comment: Okay I will add it

Comment: Are you correctly using the `Provider` tag, or, not?
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem :

I missed to add default case in my reducer :

```
const reducer = (state =initialState, action) => {
const {currencieList} = state
switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.GET_CURRENCIES:
        return {
            ...state,
            currencieList: action.currencies
        }
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```